# Is $0\in (\bigcap\limits_{n=3}^{\infty}([0,1]-[1/n,1-1/n]))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

At first I thought no since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}1/n=0$.

But then I checked that $0\in ([0,1]-[1/n,1-1/n]) $ for any positive integer $n\geq 3$.

So it is in every set. Which is the exact opposite of what I thought.

Edit: sorry people meant intersection

Comment: The answer is yes, 0 is in that union.

Comment: Note that a sufficient condition for it to be in the union of the sets is for it to be a member of $at least one$ of the sets. Only if the union was an intersection would it have to be in all of the sets; here membership in only one set suffices because we have a union, not an intersection

Comment: Set theory doesn't really care about topology. The result here would be the same if you replaced $\mathbb{R}$'s usual topology with the discrete topology.

Comment: @jgon meant intersection (fixed title)

Comment: Ah I mean either way, it's in all the sets, so it's in the intersection too.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. $0$ is in the intersection since it is in each of those sets. It has nothing to do with limits; just because a sequence of points tends to $0$ does not mean that $0$ is in the sequence. For another example consider $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty ( [0,1] \smallsetminus \{ \frac{k}{n} : k \in \mathbb{N} \} )$, which is exactly the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$, despite the fact that each of these irrationals is the limit of a sequence of numbers with exactly one from each set in the intersection.